# $\sum_{x \in X_1 \cup X_2} f(x) = \sum_{x \in X_1} f(x) + \sum_{x \in X_2} f(x).$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Proposition 8.2.6. Let $X$ be an arbitrary set (possibly uncountable), and let $f : X \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function such that the series $\sum_{x \in X} f(x)$ is absolutely convergent.
>
> (c) If $X = X_1 \cup X_2$ for some disjoint sets $X_1$ and $X_2$, then $\sum_{x \in X_1} f(x)$ and $\sum_{x \in X_2} f(x)$ are absolutely convergent, and
> $$\sum_{x \in X_1 \cup X_2} f(x) = \sum_{x \in X_1} f(x) + \sum_{x \in X_2} f(x).$$
> Conversely, if $h : X \to \mathbb{R}$ is such that $\sum_{x\in X_1} h(x)$ and $\sum_{x \in X_2} h(x)$ are absolutely convergent, then $\sum_{x \in X_1 \cup X_2} h(x)$ is also absolutely convergent, and
> $$\sum_{x \in X_1 \cup X_2} h(x) = \sum_{x \in X_1} h(x) + \sum_{x \in X_2} h(x).$$

I know that when $X$ is uncountable, then we have a countable set $X' = \{x \in X: f(x) \not=0\}$. Similarly, we have $X_1'\subset X_1$ and $X_2' \subset X_2$ such that $X_1' \cup X_2' = X'$. Therefore, the problem is reduced to the case where $X$ is countable (in the previous chapter, I've already proven the case where $X$ is finite).

The problem is that when $X', X_1', X_2'$ are all countable, I have some difficulty in proving this, using bijection. This is because, for example, $\sum_{x \in X'} f(x) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} f(g(n))$ and also $\sum_{x \in X_1'} f(x) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} f(h(n))$ for some bijection $g: \mathbb{N} \to X'$ and $h: \mathbb{N} \to X_1'$. I use bijection when proving the case for finite sets. If this is not available, how should I approach the question?

Answer (score 2):

If $\sum_{x \in X} |f(x) | <\infty$ then there is a countable set $Y=(x_n) \subseteq X$ such that $f(x)=0$ for $x \notin Y$. This makes all three sums countable sums.

Similar argument works when  $\sum_{x \in X_1} |f(x) | <\infty$  and $\sum_{x \in X_2} |f(x) | <\infty$  are finite.

In the countable case you can use even positive integers as the  indexing set for sum over $X_1$ and odd positive integers for sum over $X_2$. The equation then reduces to the form  $\sum a_n=\sum a_{2n}+\sum a_{2n-1}$

Comment: If $X', X_1', X_2'$ are all countable, are three sums equal?

Comment: @shk910 I have edited my answer. I hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

I have another answer which I'm not sure of, which I think applies in the general case.

Let $f_1:X_1\cup X_2\to R$ defined by
\begin{equation}
  f_1(x) =
  \begin{cases}
    f(x) & \text{if $x\in X_1$ } \\
    0 & \text{if $x\in X_2$}
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
Similarly, let $f_2:X_1\cup X_2\to R$ defined by
\begin{equation}
  f_2(x) =
  \begin{cases}
    0 & \text{if $x\in X_1$ } \\
    f(x) & \text{if $x\in X_2$}
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
Then $f(x)=f_1(x)+f_2(x).$

Let $F_1=\lbrace x\in X_1 : f(x)\neq 0\rbrace$

Let $F_2=\lbrace x\in X_2 : f(x)\neq 0\rbrace$

Then $F_1 \cap F_2= \phi$, $F_1 \cup F_2 = \lbrace x\in X_1 \cup X_2 : f(x)\neq 0 \rbrace$.

Then $$\sum\limits_{x\in X_1 \cup X_2}f(x)=\sum\limits_{x\in F_1\cup  F_2}f(x)=\sum\limits_{x\in F_1\cup  F_2}f_1(x)+f_2(x)=\sum\limits_{x\in F_1\cup  F_2}f_1(x)+\sum\limits_{x\in F_1\cup  F_2}f_2(x)$$ from $(a)$ in the same proposition.

Since $\sum\limits_{x\in F_1\cup  F_2}f_1(x)=\sum\limits_{x\in F_1}f_1(x)$, and $
\sum\limits_{x\in F_1}f_2(x)=0.$

Therefore $$\sum\limits_{x\in F_1}f_1(x)=\sum\limits_{x\in F_1}f_1(x)+\sum\limits_{x\in F_1}f_2(x)=\sum\limits_{x\in F_1}f_1(x)+f_2(x)=\sum\limits_{x\in F_1}f(x)=\sum\limits_{x\in X_1}f(x)$$
from $(a)$ in the same proposition.

Similarly $$\sum\limits_{x\in F_1\cup  F_2}f_2(x)=\sum\limits_{x\in F_2}f_2(x)=\sum\limits_{x\in X_2}f(x)$$

Then $$\sum\limits_{x\in X_1\cup  X_2}f(x)=\sum\limits_{x\in X_1}f(x)+\sum\limits_{x\in X_2}f(x).$$

Is my proof correct?